# Getting error when using UNION all with a query which has variable assignment

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
USE [DDRS]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[Test]    Script Date: 10/20/2019 8:59:04 PM ******/
--
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER proc [dbo].[Test]
as


begin
SELECT DISTINCT 
    DO.Contract_Number AS Contract_Number,
    'Ambiguity in contract No' AS Remarks
FROM 
    weight3 w3, Delivery_Order DO 
WHERE 
    w3.DO_UID = DO.DO_UID AND w3.ContractNo <> DO.Contract_Number 

UNION ALL

SELECT DISTINCT 
    w3.ContractNo AS contract_number,
    'Ambiguity in Transporter Name' AS Remarks
FROM 
    weight3 w3, Delivery_Order DO 
WHERE 
    w3.DO_UID = DO.DO_UID AND w3.Transporter_Name <> DO.TransporterName 
--For closed DO 
declare @latest date
declare @ContractNumber nvarchar(200)
select @latest=Max(DO.Time_stamp), @ContractNumber=DO.Contract_Number from Delivery_Order DO where DO_Status='Received' group by DO.Contract_Number
Union ALL
select w3.ContractNo as contract_number,'After closing the DO data is entered!' AS Remarks
from weight3 w3 where 
 @latest<(select distinct MAX(w3.second_time) from weight3 w3 where w3.ContractNo=@ContractNumber) and w3.ContractNo=@ContractNumber
End
```

getting the following error

> A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations.
>
> Variable assignment is not allowed in a statement containing a top level UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator.

Comment: OK. And what about that error seems unclear or disagreeable to you? You are doing the thing it says you can't so, by trying to do `select @latest=` as part of a `union`ed query.

Comment: The error is telling you the problem. You can't assign values to variables and return a dataset in the same query. This seems like an XY problem. What are you actually trying to do here.

Comment: `select @latest` must place a value in this variable. however the Union makes you having 2 or more values. that's why it is non-acceptable.

Comment: Also, why `DISTINCT` and then `UNION ALL`? It would make not sense to use `UNION` instead if you're going to get duplicate rows.

Comment: Move into the 21 century - stop using [old-style joins in the where clause](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment.

First, SQL Server does not allow a single `SELECT` to both return a result set and to assign variable values.  That is built into the language.

Second, a variable assignment pretty much assumes that the underlying query is going to return one row (or perhaps up to one row).

A `UNION ALL` query is -- presumably -- going to return multiple rows.  You might be thinking:  "Well, it *really* does return only one row, so that is okay".  However, I can see why the designers of the language would just disallow the syntax.

What can you do?

1. You can put the `UNION ALL` in a subquery and do the assignment in an outer query.
2. You can run the assignment on the first query.  If nothing is returned, try the second query.
3. You may be able to rephrase the logic so this particular query is not needed.

If (3) is of interest, I would recommend that you ask a *new* question, explain the logic, and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: let me try @Gordon Linoff